# Is there any perl simulator to play with like pycrust for python?

Tags: perl

just dig into perl and wondering if there is pycrust for perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Devel::REPL](http://p3rl.org/Devel%3a%3aREPL) is the best. Run `re.pl` after installation.

Comment: debian users can use 'sudo apt-get install libdevel-repl-perl' to install it easily :)

Comment: The equivalent RPM package name is `perl-Devel-REPL`.

Answer (score 2):

The closest is probably [perlconsole](http://sukria.net/perlconsole.html)

Comment: i didnt like this one because you couldn't turn off (easily) the strict declarations, which, of course is what you want most of the time, but for learning purposes, was a pain. I ended up hacking the /usr/share/perl5/PerlConsole/Console.pm and commenting out the "use strict" line to disable it... just remember that you did that :)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, but you can launch the interactive debugger after executing some trivial code by using something like:

```
perl -d -e 1
```

which simply drops you into the debugger after executing "1".

There's also http://www.sukria.net/perlconsole.html